# Erroring in serverHTTP but not in my code, why?

Tags: interface, go

First code: http://play.golang.org/p/OEDetydMbW

Second code: http://play.golang.org/p/QZIrWALAm_

Can somebody explain me why I am not getting error on First code, I was expecting to error out stating `missing CreateTable method`.

Comment: In the future, please include all relevant code in your post and **don't** just include a link to a code hosting site. Your post should stand alone from any other resource; consider what'd happen if play.golang.org went down in the future.

Comment: @NathanTuggy I learned from other posts stating that as play.golang.org is present so don't paste the code here and make it complicated. Anyway I don't have any problem to put here.

Comment: @KishoreVaishnav whoever told you that was exactly the opposite of right and helpful. [Always](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/269154/4099598) put the relevant portions of your code directly in your question. (Yes, that's a site moderator saying that in the link.)

Answer (score 1):

You specify an interface `Abc` with the method `CreateTable` but none of your variable are actually of type interface `Abc`
This slightly  modified version will bring the error you seek:
http://play.golang.org/p/ETdexzPYaM

```
package main

import "log"

// Abc asdlkfjaslf as
type Abc interface {
    CreateTable(a, b)
}

type a int
type b int

// Def klajsdlfkjaslfd
type Def int

// // CreateTable laksjdfljasfdl
// func (d *Def) CreateTable() {
//  log.Println("inside Def CreateTable....")
// }

func main() {
    var m1 Abc = Def(5)
    log.Println("inside main %d", m1)
}
```